# How can I set text for cell in UITableview from NSDictionary

Tags: iphone

I have an NSDictionary with 5 keys and corresponding values. How can I set the value in the cell of UITableView when I don't know the key?

`d=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Air Bus",@"ab",
     @"Boeing 787 ",@"787",@"Some Plane",
                      @"sp",nil];`

Comment: You'll need to post some code for us to help! Where is the NSDictionary coming from?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can show a list of the keys in the dictionary like this :

```
for (id key in [myDictionary allKeys])
  NSLog(@"Key : %@ => value : %@", key, [myDictionary objectForKey:key]);
```

so, for your dictionary this would show

```
ab => Air Bus
787 => Boeng 787
sp => Some Plane
```

I'm assuming that you want to show all the values in a table so you will want something like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  // Get a cell
  ...

  // Get the data to display for this cell
  int index = [indexPath indexAtPosition:1];
  NSString *key = [[d allKeys] objectAtIndex:index];
  NSString *value = [d objectForKey:key];
  [[cell textLabel] setText:value];

  return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but need to show it on table cellForRowAtIndexPath in each row

Comment: sorry, I answered while you were editing the question - see my new edit!